# How to list availble font families in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i need to provide option to change font family dynamically from the font families list in windows phone..

Question:

1. How to get available font families for windows phone?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure for WP7 but this is how you can do in WinForms app.

```
var fonts = FontFamily.Families
            .Select(ff => ff.Name)
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Silverlight doesn't support listing the Font Families.

Still, the Font Families in Windows Phone are fixed, and you can check them over on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806365%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)!